# index(max(my_list)) in list comprehension gives all instances of the max value instead of just the first occurrence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code snippet -->

```
li = [3,1,2,3]
print([x+99 if li.index(x)!=li.index(max(li)) else x-(99*(len(li)-1)) for x in li ])
```

I was expecting the output to be :

```
[-294, 100, 101, 102]
```

but the actual output on running the program was :

```
[-294, 100, 101, -294]
```

Why do i get both instances of the maximum value in the list instead of just the first occurrence?

How exactly are list comprehensions evaluated and how is that responsible for the output in my program ?

Comment: You’re comparing `li.index(x) != li.index(max(li))`. `li.index(3)` is the same both times `x == 3`. Use `for i, x in enumerate(li)` instead.

Comment: You're doing searches using [list.index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). That will always find the first occurence (if any). If you want the index of an item you found in a sequence, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: @YannVernier, I just want the first occurrence. Since I am getting both occurrence in the result, hence the question. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: The title is factually incorrect. `index` gave you the index of the first instance every time - on both sides of your comparison.

Comment: You're right but had I known my mistake, I wouldn't have to post the question in the first place. Anyway, Thanks for trying to help me out.

Comment: But you could have taken a look at `li.index(max(li))` and seen it wasn't doing that. And `[li.index(x) for x in li]`. I'm curious what you did try.

Comment: @YannVernier it was a moment of confusion and I do feel that I should have got it.

Comment: This code is needlessly inefficient. Don't call `.index` or `max` in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple `3`s in your list. The implementation of `index` is such that it finds only the index of the first occurrence of the value passed to it. Instead, use `enumerate`:

```
li = [3,1,2,3]
l1 = [x+99 if i!=li.index(max(li)) else x-(99*(len(li)-1)) for i, x in enumerate(li)]
```

Output:

```
[-294, 100, 101, 102]
```

Comment: Your code solves my problem but since index() returns the index of the first occurrence, then why are both the 3s in the list affected?

Comment: @adeen-s when your code reaches the last `3` in `[3,1,2,3]`, it attempts to find the index, which will give `0`, because the first occurrence of the last item in the list, `3`, is found at index `0`, due to the implementation of `list.index()`. Thus, the last operation, `x-(99*(len(li)-1))`, is performed because the condition `i!=li.index(max(li))` fails.

Comment: I get it now, I'll proceed to accept your answer. Thanks a lot.